# Floating images and web layout

Tags: css, layout, css-float

Im trying to separate two columns on my website by a vertical line between the two columns. I'm trying to use the "hr" tag with css styling to make it a vertical line. Can anyone suggest the css I should apply to position the three elements?

Comment: Don't do that. Use a border instead.

Comment: Those two columns are divs or table cells?

Comment: "hr" means horizontal ruler, it's not supposed to be used vertical...

Comment: the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dPXUc/ ,but using the border+margin+padding css properties is really much more usual way.

Answer (score 1):

The `<hr>` tag is for creating horizontal lines. There is no specific tag to create a vertical line, but you could create one by using a `<div>` and the vertical line properties in css.

Here is the html code. You can place it wherever you want but you have to specify the positions in the css properties.

```
<div class="vLine"></div>
```

Here the css code:

> .vLine{   width: 1px;     height: 1009px;     background-color: #F0F0F0;
>     color:#F0F0F0;  position: absolute;     left: 150px;     }

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you want to do it with `<hr />`, see http://jsfiddle.net/sZqrD/1/.

But I think http://jsfiddle.net/9V4qh/ is better